# grpc.Credentials.createSsl() - Cannot read property 'createSsl' of undefined

Tags: grpc

I am getting following error running nodejs (latest stable) & grpc (installed via npm install grpc) on win7 x64:

Relevant code:

```
var certPath = path.join(process.env.LOCALAPPDATA, 'cert', 'rpc.cert');
var cert = fs.readFileSync(certPath);
var creds = grpc.Credentials.createSsl(cert);
```

Error:

```
var creds = grpc.Credentials.createSsl();
               ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'createSsl' of undefined
```

rpc.cert is present in the path and is readable + is in PEM standard format. I guess, gRPC is throwing error, because it does not understand the format maybe ? Or what I am doing wrong here - or what am I missing ?

Thank you very much for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually just a minor API usage error. Some time within the last couple of versions, `grpc.Credentials` changed to `grpc.credentials` (with a lower-case `c`). You should be able to call `grpc.credentials.createSsl()` just fine.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was pulling my hair out, yet you have solved it in a sec. I guess I should read the release notes :)

Comment: May I actually ask you just one more thing ? With your correction, I have tried to establish a connection to grpc server, but now nodejs logs in console TLS handshake error:  Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:10000410:SSLroutines:OPENSSL_internal:SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE. Secure handshake failed with error 1. - Where should I look to solve this ? Is it unsupported cipher suite ? I need the grpc client I am connecting from to support this particular cipher suite: 'HIGH+ECDSA' . Thank you in advance very much!

Comment: Generally, you should ask something like that as a separate question. Based on that specific message, my initial guess is that this `rpc.cert` file doesn't have the certificate data to verify the server's certificate, or possibly that the server's certificate does not match the hostname that you are connecting to

Comment: Thank you very much for your tip! I'll investigate and will report back here what was the problem. And also will make such question as separate one in the future - I just did not want to spam Stack Overflow with my questions :) Thank you @murgatroid99 !

Comment: I also had the SSL_ERROR_SSL certificate error (after struggling past the incorrect documentation about `grpc.Credentials`). I had downloaded the certificate for the server but I suppose it needed an additional (chained) certificate even though I'm providing the actual cert.  I found the 'roots.pem' file in node_modules/grpc/etc, and used that and the SSL error went away.